# wrap text in A tag in a LI tag in an inline menu

Tags: html, css, css-float

Please, is it  possible to wrap the text of an `<a>` tag within a fixed size `<li>` tag in an inline menu?

Comment: Even though in this case the code should be pretty simple, it's always much more helpful to post the actual HTML referred in your question instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you use `float: left` on your `<li>` tags instead of `display: inline`. You're not supposed to use fixed width on inline elements.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CprcT/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean something like this...

```
<a href="/my/link"><li>My Link</li></a>
```

In which case, technically yes... but why would you want to? Wouldn't it make more sense to do it the other way around like so...

```
<li class="menu"><a href="/my/link">My Link</a></li>
```